# Can a timeseries with a clear trend be considered stationary?

Tags: r, time-series, trend, augmented-dickey-fuller

I performed a augmented Dickey-Fuller test on a timeseries (that clearly has a trend) and, from the results, it suggests it is stationary (p-value = 0.01). Is this possible?

```
    Augmented Dickey-Fuller Test

data:  timeseries_1
Dickey-Fuller = -5.7857, Lag order = 14, p-value = 0.01
alternative hypothesis: stationary
```

[image: Timeseries]

Answer (score 11):

From the help page:

> The general regression equation which incorporates a constant and
> a linear trend is used and the t-statistic for a first order
> autoregressive coefficient equals one is computed.

That is, `adf.test()` fits a regression using an intercept, a trend (!) and the first $k$ autoregressive terms in the series. Only *in this context* does it test whether the first autoregressive parameter is equal to one, which would indicate nonstationarity.

Thus, a trended series can definitely be stationary in the sense of `tseries::adf.test()`, namely if it is stationary *after accounting for the trend*.

Comment: That plot almost looks like it's stationary around a nonlinear trend. Does `asdf.test` try multiple different trend models, or is the nonlinearity gentle enough that the ADF test routine doesn't trip on it?

Comment: @shadowtalker: I looked at the source code, which is simple and straightforward R. It tries exactly one model as I described it here. The OP could in principle step through it with their original data.